# Is there equivalent to \Q ... \E in C# Regex

Tags: c#, regex

Is there equivalent to  \Q ... \E in C# Regex? I can't find it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent to the \Q...\E syntax in .NET as told on this [site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html).

Instead you could use the **[Regex.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx)** method :

> Escapes a minimal set of
>   characters (\, *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,),
>   ^, $,., #, and white space) by
>   replacing them with their escape
>   codes.

Answer (score 2):

Can use Regex.Escape

```
string input = "any +idea? dude";    
string pattern = @"\ *" + Regex.Escape("+idea?") + @"\ *"
Regex Expression = new Regex(pattern);

MatchCollection match = Expression.Matches(input);
```